# PayPal REST API Webhooks: Possible/allowed resource_types

Tags: rest, symfony, paypal

I am working on integrating the PayPal REST API in my Symfony 2 web app. Currently I am struggling on implementing the controller that handles the [`Webhooks`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/).

This is just a event handler, that is called by the PayPal API on different event like updates to an payment.

I configured the Webhook to consume the following events:

```
PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED
PAYMENT.SALE.DENIED
PAYMENT.SALE.PENDING
PAYMENT.SALE.REFUNDED
PAYMENT.SALE.REVERSED
```

Now I am trying to find out, which events will contain which data. The docs only say:

```
resource_type   string  Name of the resource contained in the resource property.
```

So far so good. But I was not able to find any information about what event will contain what `resource_type`. There are really a lot of different  `resource_types` and I have no idea which of these are allowed/possible when dealing with the different events.

Does anyone know where to find this information, since the PayPal docu itself is not very help full in this case.